# Custom scrollbars in websites - do they make any sense?

Tags: css, windows-os, scrollbars

Are custom scrollbars still needed today?

The only reason they were needed so far is because they are fugly on Windows. They are always visible and don't autohide and they just look bad. But I've see on youtube that in Windows 10 they changed scrollbars so now they look like on MacOS! That means there's no point anymore in using scrollbar scripts like perfect-scrollbar, right? Which btw, is anything but perfect, because it never works right with modern frameworks like vue, react etc... And it never will because graphic updates are hard-impossible to track, especially when using effects.

Just to make it clear, I am talking about scrollbars for inner elements, like some list with many items, not the browser window itself. Nobody uses custom scrollbars for the browser window anyway.

Comment: Your Question and description do not make it clear what is your exact doubt. Could you clarify? Do you mean should we use them in design, or tehnically overall should it be possible, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I think scrollbars shouldn't change unless there is a big reason behind it. The scrollbar style should be as user expects which is his browser default. changing something like this without no big reason makes usability risks for your design.